# Global function executed in all pages flutter

Tags: flutter, android-workmanager

I have to execute this portion of code in all my screen, How do I do it?

```
const task2 = "task";
Workmanager wm = Workmanager();
Widget homepage = WelcomePage();

void callbackDispatcher() {
 
  wm.executeTask((task, inputdata) async {
    switch (task) {
      case myTask:
        print("this method was called from native!");

        break;

      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        break;

      case task2:
        String uidUser = inputdata!['uid'];
        var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Utenti').doc(uidUser).get();
        var currentPos = LatLng(snap.data()!['boxes'][0]['box']['gps']['currentPosition']['lat'], 
                      snap.data()!['boxes'][0]['box']['gps']['currentPosition']['long']);
        print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'+currentPos.toString());
        
        break;
    }

    //Return true when the task executed successfully or not
    return Future.value(true);
  });


Future<void> main() async {
    
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  print(now.hour.toString() +
      ":" +
      now.minute.toString() +
      ":" +
      now.second.toString());
  //wm.registerPeriodicTask("Tester", taskName, frequency: Duration(minutes:1 ),inputData:{"data1":"hello"} );
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  wm.initialize(callbackDispatcher);

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? uid = prefs.getString("uid");
  if(uid!= null){
    wm.registerOneOffTask("1", task2, initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 1),inputData: {'string':uid.toString()});
    homepage = new PaginaIniziale();
  }
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

What i need is that executeTask works in all my screens.dart. I need the background work  executed everywhere in my code. Is there a place where i can put my code for this purpose? A function or something else?

Comment: How about [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)?

Comment: @easeccy uhm but i have to initialize always all the variables that i need for execute the task or what?

Comment: You need to use a [state management solution](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) to handle the lifecycle of the resources. [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is the most popular one.